# Recall and f1-score are pretty low (~0.55 and 0.65) for unseen instances of custom entity on transfer-learned spacy NER model

Tags: named-entity-recognition, transfer-learning, spacy-3

I have a dataset annotated with custom entity. Each data point is long text (not a single sentence), possibly with multiple entities. The corpus size is around 1200 texts. This corpus divided into train-validation-test set as follows:

- train-set(~60% of the data)
- validation set(~20% containing some instances which are not present in training set for the entity)
- test-set(~20% containing some instances that are not present in either train or validation set for entity).
  I'm using transfer learning with pretrained en_core_web_sm model.
  I have also custom function to get precision-recall-f1 score separately for unseen instances in the dataset. (based off get_ner_prf from spacy)

When i train model, the precision , recall and f1-score values reach till 1 for seen instances of the entity in the validation set , but it has very poor recall on unseen instances.

When predictions made on the test set, model has very poor performance, especially on unseen instances (~0.55 recall and ~0.65 f1 score).

Are there any recommendations to improve the performance of the model (especially for unseen instances) ?

Comment: Same thing on the spaCy forums. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/9283